# Best Practice: HTTP code for user exceeding usage limitation

Tags: http, http-headers, error-code

This is a somewhat simple question, but sadly I have not been able to find a concrete answer thus far.

We are constructing an API (we're not in production yet) which returns a large amount of data after user authentication, etc. The API system tracks the user's usage on a per second and per hour basis. When the user exceeds either of those limitations, the server returns no content and some http error code.

Presently, I'm using 406 Not Acceptable, but I don't believe that's the best code to use. Its been suggested that 509 Bandwidth Limit Exceeded would be a good one, but I wonder if there is a code which would be considered best practice for my situation. Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Status code 429 comes to mind:

> [RFC 6585, section 4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6585#section-4): 429 Too Many Requests

> The 429 status code indicates that the user has sent too many
> requests in a given amount of time ("rate limiting").

> The response representations SHOULD include details explaining the
> condition, and MAY include a Retry-After header indicating how long
> to wait before making a new request.

Comment: Good find, thank you. This seems to fit my scenario a lot better than 406.

Answer (score 1):

Well, since you've found no applicable error code, I'd guess there isn't one. In this situation, if I were you, I'd use stick with your 406 or anything like that, just decide on something and keep using it. The browser doesn't care anyway and the API's are used by people that will accept whatever code you return and deduce it's a rule - "if I exceed the usage, I get 406". I think it doesn't really matter what the magic number is.

Comment: I don't think 406 is applicable: [RFC 2616, 10.4.7 406 Not Acceptable](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-10.4.7): _"not acceptable
   according to the accept headers sent in the request"_. That is not the case.

Comment: Good point, d33tah. I just wanted something that would make sense. Good info CodeCaster. I agree, 406 just didn't seem like the right code for that reason; hence why I'm looking for an alternative.